# Led matrix row bits don't shift

Tags: vhdl

I am new to VHDL and I am trying to do a simple application with a led matrix (8x8). My goal is to turn on the leds of the matrix so I can see a smiley face. For some reason none of the leds turn on.

In order to see what's wrong I tried to turn on all leds on each line at a time by commenting the case statement and giving cols<="00000000" before the statement, the result is that the only line that turns on is the first, it keeps turning on and off each second.

I made the frequency divider for 1 second just to see if the code works correctly.

```
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity main is
    Port ( clk : in STD_LOGIC;
           rows : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           cols : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end main;

architecture Behavioral of main is

signal count: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0):= "00000001";
signal clk1Hz: std_logic_vector(26 downto 0);

begin

process(clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        if clk1Hz = X"5F5E0FF" then
            clk1Hz <= "000" & X"000000";
        else
            clk1Hz <= clk1Hz + 1;
        end if;

        if clk1Hz(26) = '1' then
            if count = "10000000" then
                count <= "00000001";
             else 
                count(7 downto 1) <= count(6 downto 0);
                count(0) <= '0';
            end if;

         rows <= count;

        case count is
            when "00000001" => cols <= "11111111";
            when "00000010" => cols <= "11011011";
            when "00000100" => cols <= "11011011";
            when "00001000" => cols <= "11111111";
            when "00010000" => cols <= "00111100";
            when "00100000" => cols <= "10000001";
            when "01000000" => cols <= "11000011";
            when "10000000" => cols <= "11111111";
            when others => cols <= "11111111";
         end case;
     end if;


    end if;  


end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you realize that `if clk1Hz(26) = '1' then` stays true from X"4000000" to X"5F5E0FF"?
You most likely want to change count only on the exact X"4000000" value, no? And not continuously for 1/3rd of the time...

Comment: I solved the problem, I made a mistake by comparing the last bit to '1', I replaced that statement with a rising_edge and now everything works fine. Thank you!

Comment: For info, even if rising_edge() works in simulation, it likely won't work on target (fail synthesis). See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795774/is-rising-edge-in-vhdl-synthesizable    and in that case you can test the full value or check that the one bit was 0 at the previous clock cycle

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you didn't simulate this.  The clk1Hz signal wasn't initialized and wasn't reset.  It won't spin in sim without this, since it initializes to X.  However, on hardware it will work just fine.

So, when your clk counter hits x400_0000, bit (26) is set and your row/col shifters start going like mad for 1/3 of a second. Then when the clk counter resets, all activity stops.
Is this really what you want?  I can see from simulating this that rows and cols are both shifting correctly, albeit for only a third of a second.

During the pause, rows stops at 0x80, and cols at 0xFF.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem, You were right, at x400_0000 bit(26) was set on 1 and instead of comparing it to 1, I had to check if rising_edge(bit(26)). Not it works fine. Thank you!